# HDF5 Links to Events in Dataset

Tags: python, bioinformatics, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to use HDF5 to store time-series EEG data.  These files can be quite large and consist of many channels, and I like the features of the HDF5 file format (lazy I/O, dynamic compression, mpi, etc).

One common thing to do with EEG data is to mark sections of data as 'interesting'.  I'm struggling with a good way to store these marks in the file.  I see soft/hard links supported for linking the same dataset to other groups, etc -- but I do not see any way to link to sections of the dataset.

For example, let's assume I have a dataset called EEG containing sleep data.  Let's say I run an algorithm that takes a while to process the data and generates indices corresponding to periods of REM sleep.  What is the best way to store these index ranges in an HDF5 file?

The best I can think of right now is to create a dataset with three columns -- the first column is a string and contains a label for the event ("REM1"), and the second/third column contains the start/end index respectively.  The only reason I don't like this solution is because HDF5 datasets are pretty set in size -- if I decide later that a period of REM sleep was mis-identified and I need to add/remove that event, the dataset size would need to change (and deleting the dataset/recreating it with a new size is suboptimal).  Compound this by the fact that I may have MANY events (imagine marking eyeblink events), this becomes more of a problem.

I'm more curious to find out if there's functionality in the HDF5 file that I'm just not aware of, because this seems like a pretty common thing that one would want to do.

Comment: How about using hyperslabs and regions? Or you could write the "REM1" as an attribute with it's data being the start and end index. Thoughts?

Comment: Hyperslabs and Regions are exactly what I'm using to slice up the file.  My question lies in the ability to store these hyperslab selections/regions as 'links' in the file.  The same way a soft link can link to another group, a dataset soft link could simply be a hyperslab selection into another dataset.  I considered using attributes, but I need attributes to indicate things like sample rate, channel labels, etc.  I'm currently using an expandable dataset with event name, start/stop index, and valid bit -- deleting an event simply sets the valid entry in this 'event' dataset from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a *Region Reference* — essentially, a way to store a reference to a slice of your data. In [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/refs.html#using-region-references), you create them with the `regionref` property and numpy slicing syntax, so if you have a dataset called `ds` and your `start` and `end` indexes of your REM period, you can do:

```
rem_ref = ds.regionref[start:end]
ds.attrs['REM1'] = rem_ref
ds[ds.attrs['REM1']]  # Will be a 1-d set of values
```

You can store regionrefs pretty naturally — they can be attributes on a dataset, objects in a group, or you can create a regionref-type dataset and store them in there.

In your case, I might create a group ("REM_periods" or something) and store the references in there. Creating a "REM_periods" dataset and storing the regionrefs there is reasonable too, but you run into the whole "datasets tend not to be variable-length very well" thing.

Storing them as attrs on the dataset might be OK, too, but it'd get awkward if you wanted to have more than one event type.